# Temperature dependence of rubber elastic modulus

Tags: temperature, material-science, elasticity, polymers

Why does the elastic modulus of rubber increase with temperature? I read the article on rubber elasticity and it showed that the modulus increases with the temperature (rubber shrinks as heated). But I want to know why (intuitively elastic modulus should decrease with temperature).

Answer (score 2):

There’s a great explanation for this [here](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/stiffness-of-rubber/thermodynamics.php).

Essentially, you can model rubber as a mess of long, tangled molecules. When the rubber is unstretched, the molecules are more tangled, so in a higher entropy state. Stretching the rubber untangles the molecules, lowering the entropy.

At higher temperature, the change in entropy results in more heating of the rubber (as $\Delta Q = T \Delta S$), so the force required to extend the rubber increases; the rubber gets stiffer.